# loop and display through a vector of images

Tags: c++, loops, opencv, vector

I am using opencv and c++. I am doing a very simple program. What is does is it takes 3 images in a vector mat,convert those images to hsv and again stores the hsv's of the original image in a vector. I want to display all the 3 hsv images obtained. But when my program loops, it displays only the last hsv image in the vector. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/z7FBrtxs.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<Mat> imgs;

    Mat left=imread("left.jpg");
    Mat front=imread("front.jpg");
    Mat right=imread("right.jpg");

    imgs.push_back(left);
    imgs.push_back(front);
    imgs.push_back(right);


    vector<Mat> hsvs;
    Mat left_hsv;
    Mat front_hsv;
    Mat right_hsv;

    cvtColor(left,left_hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(front,front_hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(right,right_hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);

    hsvs.push_back(left_hsv);
    hsvs.push_back(front_hsv);
    hsvs.push_back(right_hsv);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        imshow("hsv",hsvs[i]);
    }
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    imshow("hsv",hsvs[i]);
    waitKey(0); //Note: wait for user input for every image
}
```

or show them in three different named windows (see documentation).

Comment: if i want to display each hsv in a separate window at once,how can i achieve this please?

Answer (score 4):

This

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    imshow("hsv",hsvs[i]);
}
waitKey(0);
```

means that you are displaying all images in the window named "hsv". And after displaying the last one, you wait for user input. Thus, the images are actually all showed in the window, in sequence, it's just that they switch so fast you never see it.
Change it to

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    imshow("hsv",hsvs[i]);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

and you should be good.
This change means each image will be shown in the "hsv" window, and then wait for you to push a button before showing the next image.

You could also show multiple windows at once by just renaming the windows to "hsv1", "hsv2", etc.

Comment: if i want to display each hsv in a separate window,how can i achieve this please?

Comment: You change `imshow("hsv",hsvs[i]);` to `imshow(window_name,hsvs[i]);` where `window_name` is a string you can build like `sprintf(window_name, "hsv%d", i)` inside the loop. This gives you the window names "hsv0", "hsv1", ...

Answer (score 1):

As there are no coordinates provided, I guess all images are drawn in the same default place (a viewport origin), and the last image was painted over all previous ones.